# Duplicate numers in python

Tags: python, python-3.2

write a python program.  All adjacent duplicates. For example, if the input is
1 3 3 4 5 5 6 6 6 2, the
program should print 3 5 6.

this is what I have so far:

```
print("Take out repeating numbers")

def main():

    a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    b = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    c = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    d = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    e = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    f = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    g = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    if a == a: 
        print(a)
    elif a == b:
        print(a)
    elif a == c:
        print(a)
    elif a == d:
        print(a)
    elif a == e:
        print(a)
    elif a == f:
        print(a)
    else:
        print(a)

    if b == a:
        print(b)
    elif b == b:
        print(b)
    elif b == c:
        print(b)
    elif b == d:
        print(b)
    elif b == e:
        print(b)
    elif b == f:
        print(b)
    else:
        print(b)

    if c == a:
        print(c)
    elif c == b:
        print(c)
    elif c == c:
        print(c)
    elif c == d:
        print(c)
    elif c == e:
        print(c)
    elif c == f:
        print(c)
    else:
        print(c)
        '''
    if d == a or d == b  or d == c or d == d or d == e or d == f or d == g:
        print(d)
    if e == a or e == b  or e == c or e == d or e == e or e == f or e == g:
        print(e)
    if f == a or f == b  or f == f or f == d or f == e or f == f or f == g:
        print(f)
    if g == a or g == b  or g == c or g == d or g == e or g == f or g == g:
        print(g)    
    '''

    print("The repeating numbers are: " , a, b, c, d, e, f, g,)

main()
```

It is just printing out all the input

Comment: You might want to look into loops..

Comment: List slicing would also help you (presuming you restructure how you're holding onto values).  `nums[0:2]` -> two elements at the front of a list.

Comment: Because `a == a` and `b == b` are always `True`, the entire list is printed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one-line [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), using the [`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) function from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module:

```
import itertools as it

lst = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 2]

[k for k, v in it.groupby(lst) if len(list(v)) > 1]
=> [3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_set = []
input_num = 0

while (input_num >= 0):

    input_num = int(input("Please enter a number or -1 to finish"))
    if (input_num < 0):
        break
    input_set.append(input_num)

print(input_set)

dup = 0
new_list = []
unique_list = []

for i in range(0,len(input_set)-1):
    if input_set[i]==input_set[i+1] or input_set[i] == input_set[i-1]:
        new_list.append(input_set[i])

[unique_list.append(item) for item in new_list if item not in unique_list]
print(unique_list)
```

Comment: Please also add how you're solving the problem given that the question seems like homework.

Answer (score 0):

my answer may be too late. But, for this question.. you can retrieve the duplicate adjacent number using if statement inside a boolean and a while loop statement as code below.

First set the boolean status as True.

In your while statement if number input is more than 0, proceed with if statement where you need to check whether the status is False and if the next number is the same with the previous number. Then retrieve the adjacent number but make sure to convert it to string before concatenate it with other adjacent number.

```
count = 0
previous = 0
duplicate = ""

num = int(input("\nPlease enter a number or -1 to finish : "))
previous = num
status = True

while num >= 0.0:
    # determine the adjacent duplicates
    if not status and num == previous:
        duplicate = duplicate + " " + str(num)
        print(duplicate)

    status = False
    previous = num
    count = count + 1
    num = int(input("Please enter a number or -1 to finish : "))

if count > 0:
    print(duplicate)
else:
    print("Finish")
```

Hope my code may able to help you. Others, feel free to criticize and upgrade my code for other people reference.